# Infix validation using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

You can use [this link](https://regex101.com) to evaluate my regex.

I'm trying to validate an infix input whether it's in the right form or not.
This is my test cases:

```
1 --> (12+4)^3-((13+2)-(4*5))    //should be correct
2 --> )3+7(                      //should be wrong
3 --> 2++                        //should be wrong
4 --> 2+4-                       //should be wrong
5 --> (19*7))                    //should be wrong
6 --> 2+8                        //should be correct
```

So now you might know what's on my mind . I red many websites and questions and concluded that I should use **recursive regex**.
So I tried to recognize the pattern and I came with this(incorrect version):

```
(^(\(?[0-9]+(\+\-\*\/\^)[0-9]*\))|^([0-9]+(\+\-\*\/\^)[0-9]+(?1)*))(?1)*$
```

And I implemented that in python using **regex (not re)** library:

```
import regex
regex.search(r"(^(\(?[0-9]+(\+\-\*\/\^)[0-9]*\))|^([0-9]+(\+\-\*\/\^)[0-9]+(?1)*))(?1)*$","(12+4)^3-((13+2)-(4*5))") is not None
```

The expected output should be **True** but my output is **False** .
I know my pattern is incorrect and need your help.If you know better pattern that would be nice!Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? A simple state machine parser would be a much saner and easier to maintain solution…

Comment: This is inherently not a task for regex. You need to define your accepted grammar (which will most likely _not_ be regular), and then write a parser.

Comment: @phipsgabler Why not?

Comment: @KellyBundy the grammar is not defined, so we can't really know. But it looks like an expression language with parentheses -- and you need unbounded state to remember the matching parentheses.

Comment: @phipsgabler And recursive regex can do that, no? You somewhat sound like you just learned that in a theory of computation class and aren't familiar with today's actual regexes.

Comment: Ha :D No, that was long ago. But look: I'm also the kind of person who likes to plane and saw boards by hand. You can do that -- however, I wouldn't recommend it to anyone, unless for the fun of it. There are just better tools. Coming back to regex: yes, todays "regex" can do that, but there's a reason this is an oxymoron (and not implemented in standard `re`). I can see no advantage except that one doesn't have to deviate from an already known syntax. (Modern Excel also has LET and LAMBDA. I still don't recommend programming in Excel.)

Comment: @phipsgabler What's that reason it's not implemented in standard `re`?

Comment: @KellyBundy DFA compilation and optimization (which works for "real" regexes) are well-studied, and have certain complexity guarantees. Fancy non-regular features are not that hard to add, but then you lose those guarantees and the algorithms. See, e.g., what [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/WhyRE2) writes about its choices, and especially the referenences therein.

Comment: And coming back to my original point: it's not that hard to accidentially hit exponential backtracking cases with "fancy" regexes. OTOH, if you use standard parsing technology, you again have (at least) polynomial guarantees. And better readability. (Of course it's a choice. For just hacking something on the spot, why not fancy regexes.)

Comment: @phipsgabler You make it sound like standard `re` only supports "real" regexes, corresponding to regular languages,, and that it guarantees linear time. Neither is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I ... concluded that I should use recursive regex.

This is indeed possible with a recursive regex, which is what the `regex` library supports.

One of the mistakes in your attempt is that `(\+\-\*\/\^)` does not represent a *choice* of operator, but requires **all** of them to appear in that sequence. You need `[+*/^-]` syntax.

I would suggest this regular expression:

```
result = regex.match(r"^(([+-]*\d+|\((?1)\))([+^*/-](?2))*)$", s)
```

This assumes that your input has no spaces, and the numeric literals are (signed) integers.

Explanation:

- `[+-]*`: any sequence of these two characters, which serve as *unary* operators. `+` is in that sense a useless operator, but it is allowed.
- `\d+`: any non-empty sequence of digits, representing an unsigned integer
- `(?1)`: recursion. This will use the whole regular expression -- except for the `^` and `$` anchors! -- in a recursive way. With the surrounding, literal parentheses, this allows for expression nesting.
- `[+^*/-]`: any *binary* operator (extend with more operators as needed)
- `(?2)`: to match the second operand of a binary operator, re-using the same pattern as was used to match the first operand.